# Running Android App for all the android device

Tags: android

I am new to android and I have develop the app with 5.0.1 target. However, when I run the app in my mobile which has 4.4 version of android, it does not run the app that is due to version mismatch. My question is, in which version we can develop the android app which can run on all android device?

Comment: look ino the following..http://developer.android.com/training/basics/supporting-devices/platforms.html

Answer (score 0):

If you work on eclipse set in the `AndroidManifest.xml` the `minSdkVersion` to something below 20 (i recommend 15) and it will work also on your device:

```
<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="15"
          android:targetSdkVersion="21"/>
```

Here you can find the sdk values for versions:
http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/uses-sdk-element.html

If you work on Android Studio go in your `build.gradle` file and set under `defaultConfig` your preferences on sdk:

```
defaultConfig {
    applicationId "mybundleID"
    minSdkVersion 15
    targetSdkVersion 21
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
}
```

**UPDATE**

I read now that you wanted to support ALL android devices so you can put `minSdkVersion` equal to 1. But i think that this is the worst thing you can do! Putting the `minSdkVersion` you will not be able to use some method and some libraries. You have to support the majority of the devices for a good application. As i said values between 11 and 15 are the most used now!